# How do I do multiple string replacements in multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, str-replace

I have an array called `$queries` that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => SELECT * FROM StudentRecord WHERE Year = '%YEAR%' AND Session = '%SESSION%' AND StudentID = '%SID%'; 
    [1] => SELECT * FROM Student_ApplicationRecord WHERE ApplicationYear = '%YEAR%' AND Session%SESSION% = 1; 
)
```

I also have a second array called `$variables` that looks like this:

```
$variables = array('YEAR' => 2016, 'SESSION' => 1, 'SID' => $_SESSION['sid']);
```

I want to replace the variables in `$queries` with the correct values in `$variables`.

I have tried many solutions and the best I've come up with so far is:

```
foreach ($queries as $query)
    foreach($variables as $key=>$value)
        $newqueries[] = str_replace("%".$key."%", $value, $query);
```

However this is only replacing one variable at a time in each query.

i.e. when I do:

```
foreach ($newqueries as $query)
    print ($query);
```

The result for each query is:

```
SELECT * FROM StudentRecord 
WHERE Year = '%YEAR%' AND Session = '%SESSION%' AND SID = '%SID%'; 

SELECT * FROM StudentRecord 
WHERE Year = '%YEAR%' AND Session = '1' AND SID = '%SID%';

SELECT * FROM StudentRecord 
WHERE Year = '%YEAR%' AND Session = '%SESSION%' AND SID = '1234';
```

What I want is a final array `$newqueries` that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => SELECT * FROM StudentRecord WHERE Year = '2016' AND Session = '1' AND StudentID = '1234'; 
    [1] => SELECT * FROM Student_ApplicationRecord WHERE ApplicationYear = '2016' AND Session1 = 1; 
)
```

Can anyone help me out please? I apologise if this has been asked before but I have not been able to find any similar questions.

Comment: Why don't you use prepared statement with parameter binding instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) accepts arrays for the `$search` and `$replace` arguments you could use that.

```
$search = ['%YEAR%', '%SESSION%', '%SID%'];
$replace = ['2016', '1', $_SESSION['id']];
$newQueries = [];
foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $newQueries[] = str_replace($search, $replace, $query);
}
```